# Listbox not updating within user control wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml, listbox

I've been struggling for a while with getting a listbox to update in WPF. I have a user control that includes a listbox. I then embed this usercontrol within another user control.

```
public partial class MyClass : UserControl
{
    private Thread myThread;

    public MyClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    ObservableCollection<String> sampleData = new ObservableCollection<String>();
    public ObservableCollection<String> SampleData
    {
        get
        {
            if (sampleData.Count <= 0)
            {
                sampleData.Add("1");
                sampleData.Add("2");
            }
            return sampleData;
        }
    }

    public void StartMyThread()
    {
        if (myThread == null)
        {
            myThread = new Thread(ThreadProgram);
            myThread.Start();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateFromThread(string text)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            UpdateList(text);
        }));
    }

    private void UpdateList(string text)
    {       
         sampleData.Add(text);
    }

private void ThreadProgram()
{
    UpdateFromThread("my text");
    //other stuff
}
```

My XAML for the user control that contains the list box contains:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SampleData}"/>
</Grid>
```

and the place where I embed my control is here:

```
<TabControl SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged" Name="tabCtrl">
    <TabItem Header="MyListboxTab">
        <Service:MyClass Margin="0,0,-1,0"/>
    </TabItem>
```

It updates initially with the "1" and "2" and I can use a messagebox to display the text instead. I've checked and my updates to the listbox are definitely being called, they just don't display.

It's also worth noting that the list updates when calling `sampleData.Add("clicked");` from a button click.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What happens if you remove the threading? And just update the list from a button click or something? I guess this will work.

Comment: Yeah you're right - it updates from a button click. Just to confirm, the .Add is being called, I thought the invoke would allow it to work?

Comment: Yes it should, but know that invoke will schedule execution and will fire when the framework decides it is necessary to do so. The results I got from this were so different with every execution that I decided to create a thread safe list and update the observable collection from the UI thread.

Comment: There should be a better solution but as my project was already overdue I took this shortcut.

Comment: Do you think that will solve my issue? Would you be able to explain how to do that? Sorry - I'm new to wpf and C#.